# Working on a branch with a dependence on another branch that is being reviewed

Tags: git, branching

How does git help deal with the scenario below:

I have a task broken down into 2 parts: backend task and frontend task. I make a pull request to merge the backend changes and wait for it to be merged (and address feedback). While waiting, I can't really work on the frontend changes because it depends on backend changes and those are not available on the master branch yet.

What is the best way to pull in changes to frontend changes branch from the backend changes branch while it is still being reviewed?

Comment: Why can't you write it against your not-yet-reviewed backend code?

Comment: Does your team have some sort of agreed-on technique for handling this situation? If not, maybe you should agree on something like this, since it's a fairly common situation.

Comment: There is none. That is the reason why I asked this question.
I got very good suggestions. I will try out the suggestions and see how they work out for me.

Comment: @user253751 Separation of concerns.

Comment: @RobinHood Silly reason.

Answer (score 127):

## Hold on, skip merging

For this approach, you do *not* want to merge your `feature_a` into `feature_b` repeatedly.

Rebasing has been mentioned in other answers, but only for rebasing things onto `master`. What you want to do in your case is:

- Start your `feature_b` from `feature_a`, i.e.:

  ```
  git checkout feature_a
  git checkout -b feature_b
  ```
- Whenever `feature_a` changes while it is waiting to get merged into `master`, you *rebase* `feature_b` on it:

  ```
  ... commit something onto feature_a ...
  git checkout feature_b
  git rebase feature_a
  ```
- Finally, as soon as `feature_a` has been merged into `master`, you simply get the new `master` and rebase `feature_a`onto it a last time:

  ```
  git checkout master
  git pull origin master
  git checkout feature_b
  git rebase --onto master feature_a feature_b
  ```

  This final rebase will graft all commits that are dangling from the `feature_a`commit (which is now irrelevant as it has been merged into `master`) right onto `master`. Your `feature_b` is now a simple, standard branch going right from `master`.

EDIT: inspired from the comments, a little heads up: if you need to make some change which affects *both* features, then be sure to make it in `feature_a` (and then rebase as shown). Do *not* make it in two different commits in both branches, even if may be tempting; as `feature_a` is part of the history of `feature_b`, having the single change in two different commits will be semantically wrong and possibly lead to conflicts or "resurrections" of unwanted code, later.

Comment: With rebasing on `feature_a` multiple times, you may later run into problems, when `feature_a` itself has been rebased in the meantime. As result of running `git checkout feature_b; git rebase feature_a` you may get conflicts or some funny commits containing commits reverting new changes of `feature_a`. This is usually solvable by using `--interactive` and skipping commits taken from the old version of the other branch (I had to do this several times recently).

Comment: @maaartinus, thanks for the heads-up, I have not run into such issues myself. As `rebase` does many more individual steps than a simple `merge`, there is surely a sightly higher chance for it to create conflicts; on the other hand `merge` would just be semantically quite wrong to do in this case.

Comment: I guess, `merge` would have similar or worse problems (a conflict is not as bad as getting in an unwanted change). I view a branch as sequence of *wanted* changes preceded by many *unrelated* changes (logically belonging to a different branch). When repeatedly rebasing with the same branch, I always remove the unrelated changes as I know they'll come in anyway (possibly in an updated shape) and it works fine.

Comment: @maaartinus, I have added a small addendum about this (to consistently make changes which need to go into both branches only in the base branch, not in two different commits).

Comment: Nice technique. It's how I always do it as well. `git rebase --onto` FTW :D

Comment: Does this method work if `feature_a` is merged into master using a "squash merge"?

Comment: Yes, whether it was a squash or a normal merge would make no difference at all. @EverPresent

Comment: It worked for me. A comment here: my `feature_b` was on PR too (just to run some Jenkins pipelines) and once I did the `rebase --onto...` I couldn't push to the origin. Git recommended me to do a pull and then push, so it doesn't worked. Then I deleted the origin branch, and do all the workflow and works as expected.

Comment: Do I then force push? Because I get `hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

Comment: A rebase always requires --force on the next push, yes. You'll need to make sure that there are no important changes you want to keep on the origin branch, and possibly inform other developers about this so they are not confused afterwards... @BurakKaymakci

Answer (score 47):

I have this problem too sometimes. Git is very flexible. Here's one way you can do it.

Your first branch `featureA` is up for review.

Your second branch `featureB` is in development and depends on the code in the `featureA` branch.

Merge the `featureA` branch into the `featureB` branch.

If you make changes to the `featureA` branch then you should merge the `featureA` branch into the `featureB` branch again to incorporate the changes.

You should also make sure to merge `featureA` into the main trunk first, otherwise when you merge `featureB` into the main trunk you will inadvertently also merge `featureA`. Once `featureA` is merged into the main trunk you can get rid of the `featureA` branch as `featureB` only depends on the main trunk now.

I prefer it when my feature branches do not depend on each other but sometimes they do and you have to roll with it.

Comment: This makes sense.

Does this allow for undoing the merging of `featureA` onto `featureB` if need be?

Comment: There's no undo operation but as @9000 mentions, you could make a new branch and cherry pick the commits you want from `featureA` into that if you had to start over again. It's good to think of Git branches as disposable. They are cheap and easy, you can always make a new branch. You could even make a test branch off your `featureB` branch if you wanted to play around with something that you weren't sure about, and then scrap it if it didn't work out, or merge it back down to your `featureB` branch if it did.

Comment: Merging will create a mess that will be difficult (not impossible) to roll-back. I'd reather cherry-pick or rebase (ie: cherry-pick everything in featureA at the base of featureB). See 9000's answer.

Comment: This creates a complex history that will be a problem for many years to come whenever someone wants to understand what code was changed for featureA and featureB

Comment: @ian: Constant rebasing creates as simple a history as it gets: two features look sequential as a stream of changes, even if these changes were not made in this exact sequence. Git is not about chronology; it is an algebra of patches.

Comment: if featureA is updated, featureB should be rebased **not** merged

Comment: Noted and some of the other answers talk about this. I haven't used `rebase` before myself. I believe the result is the same but `rebase` leaves a much cleaner commit history on the `featureB` branch.

Comment: What if featureA (I will call refactorA) is just refactoring where possibly lot of code/files moves around and it may not make it to master before featureB or may not go to master at all? In such case, if we merge refactorA into featureB, we will have to revert back refactorA changes before merging featureB into master. There is down side also when we don't merge. Because if refactorA makes it to master before featureB, then we will get conflicts when we update featureB with master (i.e.master > featureB) and those are not easy when lot of code has been moved around. So what to do?

Answer (score 33):

You already have a branch on which your every feature branch depends, and which keeps changing. It's called `master`.

The typical way for a feature branch to stay in sync with `master` is to stay *on top* of it. When `master` changes, you normally `git fetch origin master:master && git rebase master` in your branch's working directory.

You can do the very same thing with another feature branch: keep fetching it and rebasing on top of it.

If, for some reason, you'll need to move your changes to a different branch, you can cherry-pick *your* commits, which are never mixed with other branch's commits.

Comment: But I think the scenario is that feature-b needs the code that is in feature-a, branching from master isn't going to be very helpful. Where should I start? Should I branch from feature-a and keep those in sync until feature-a is reintegrated with master, and then rebase from master to feature-b?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: you can of course base `feature-b` on `feature-a`, and do a rebase time after time as `feature-a` is changing. This is a typical way to make a large change observable: split it into `part-A` (based off `master`), `part-B` (based off `part-A`), and more if needed. Then make a pull request for each part, and reviewers have easier time looking at smaller, logically grouped pieces.

Comment: will it matter if I rebase part-b with part-a vs. part-b with master in terms of the PR? I just want to make sure my changes aren't showing part-a changes as changes in part-b. Also, if I merge vs. rebase, how will that affect the part-b PR? Every time I think I understand the effects, I get some different result lol

Answer (score 5):

In this case where the frontend task has a critical dependency on the backend code, and you want to start work on the frontend before the backend is finalised and accepted on master, I would simply start the frontend task as a feature branch coming off from the backend branch, rather than branching the frontend on master.

A feature branch that lives long enough needs to merge in changes from master occaisionally (to make sure you to reconcile any merge or semantic conflicts as part of dev work on the feature branch, rather than as part of the "review, qa, merge-to-master" process). So you do that on your front end branch, and when the backend work has been accepted to master, you'll get any minor changes that were made to the backend as part of its review/acceptance automatically, by the same route you'd get any other code changes on master.

If it turns out the backend branch needs a lot more work and it continues to change over a period of time *before* being merged to master (say if major problems are found during review), then you you'd probably want to do periodic merges directly from the backend branch into the frontend branch (so you don't keep basing all of your frontend work on obsolete backend code). This is easy if you're the only developer doing both features (since you know if you yourself make any major changes), but even if both features end up being worked on in parallel by different devs it should be fine; you just have to stay in communication (which you would need to anyway, if you're working on tasks in parallel where one has a critical dependency on the other).

If it turns out that the whole backend branch needs to be abandoned and will never be merged (it sounds like this would be a pretty major deal that would rarely happen), then you either cherry-pick your commits to a new branch coming off master without the backend work, or you apply reverse commits that remove all the backend code to the frontend branch. But as I can see it would be more likely to pause the frontend work until you'd figure out what was going to replace the backend you're throwing out, and then decide what to do.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see the problem here.

You already have this every time with your `master` branch, which keeps changing while features are developed and then merged.

So, in your concrete example, you first create the `feature_xxx_backend` branch and develop the backend changes. When this is done, the branch is up to review and will be merged into `master` once the review is complete.

So, simply start another branch, `feature_yyy_frontend`. You will probably want to branch directly from `feature_xxx_backend`, so that you have those changes already in your branc. then simply develop the frontend feature asif the branch were `master`.

When the `feature_xxx_backend` branch changes, e.g. because there are things that come up during review that need to be adressed, simply do these changes and merge them into the `feature_yyy_frontend` branch. Then continue on the frontend branch.

Once the review of the backend branch is completed, it gets merged into `master`. At this point, it would be wise to *rebase* the `feature_yyy_frontend` branch onto `master`, so that the reviewers only need to review the *new* changes that this branch contributes to `master`, and not need to re-review the changes made for the backend (which have already been approved).

This can also be done when you have two, three or more dependent branches. If you have two feature branches you depend on, simple make a derived branch that has both feature merged in. Branch from there, develop the third feature, merge both feature branches along the way when each of those change. When both features are done and get merged into either the derived branch, rebase onto that, or if they get merged into master, rebase onto master.

**Rebasing** (as suggested above) is really powerful and helps keeping a clean log of the changes, making reviews much easier.

Answer (score 2):

As Polygnome mentioned, you can actually merge your frontend branch with your backend branch instead of the masters. Even with the current branch setup you have now, you can simply do:

```
git checkout frontend
git merge backend
```

or simply

```
git merge backend frontend
```

Keep in mind though that if backend changes are not accepted and more work is needed, you'll have to merge updates from the backend into the frontend to avoid conflicts. Once the changes are accepted into the master, you can rebase your frontend on the master to get rid of the backend merge commits.

Technically you could also do everything with rebase, but that will mess up the commit history of your frontend branch. Where I'm coming from, this is considered bad practice. YMMV

Comment: "Weird that nobody mentioned that you can actually merge your frontend branch with your backend branch instead of the masters:" This *has* already been mentioned, e.g. in my own answer.

Comment: @Polygnome frontend does not have to be branched directly from backend. They can both be branched from the master as well, but you can still merge them. So your answer doesn't mention that actually.

Comment: Actually, my answer does not suggest that you branch directlly from backend,it just saiys that thats probably the route to go (since you merge those changes into the frontend branch anyways).

Comment: @Polygnome then I misunderstood your answer. Updated especially for you :-)

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this, but please tell me where I'm wrong, so I can learn something too.

Answer (score 1):

Most answers in here correctly describe the process of merging the changes from the second branch to the first, but they do not address how to minimize the amount of conflicts that you may need to resolve.

Whenever you have two sets of big changes that you want to review individually (like `featureA` and `featureB`), create a PR that's NOT meant to be merged, but to gather early feedback on a PoC of `featureA`.

People will be able to review it quickly (it's just a PoC), and the objective is to validate the general design or approach.

Then, you can keep working on feature A, create a pull request for it and branch and work on feature B.

The big difference is that now you can expect `featureA` to not change radically: the design and approach were already validated. The code review and required changes may be subtle and local rather than a "woops, you need a different approach". This will minimize the amount of work that you need to do to later on merge `featureB` on `featureA`'s code, regardless of the method you chose.